# Adding dynamic value to state in textbox attribute

Tags: reactjs

I am iterating a state property in a textbox like this:

```
{this.state.selectedQuestion.map(e=>{
    return (<ul>
    <li key={e.id}> {e.id}</li>
    <li key={e.id}> {e.question}</li>
    <li key={e.id}> <ul> {e.options.map((t,a)=>{
       return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
    })}</ul> </li>
    <li><button onClick={()=>this.editQuestion(e)}>Edit</button></li>
    </ul>
    )
    })}
```

now my state is like this:

```
this.state ={
    selectedQuestion:[],
    editValue0:'',
    editValue1:'',
    editValue2:'',
    editValue3:''
}
```

and the onchange event `onChange={this.checkRadioChange}` is like this:

```
checkRadioChange=(event)=>{

 this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value},()=>{
   // console.log('this.state.selectedQuestion[0].options: ',this.state.selectedQuestion[0].options)

    console.log("THIS.STATE",this.state)
})
```

the problem is that i am not able to equate the  dynamic value in input to the respective state properties, something like :

`return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)`

should change to

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue0" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>) 
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue1" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue2" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue3" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

as the `li` is iterating. So I tried something like:

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value={this.state.editvalue + {a}} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

and

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value={this.state.editvalue + a}" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

adding dynamic value to state in textbox attribute

I am iterating a state property in a textbox like this:

```
{this.state.selectedQuestion.map(e=>{
    return (<ul>
    <li key={e.id}> {e.id}</li>
    <li key={e.id}> {e.question}</li>
    <li key={e.id}> <ul> {e.options.map((t,a)=>{
       return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
    })}</ul> </li>
    <li><button onClick={()=>this.editQuestion(e)}>Edit</button></li>
    </ul>
    )
    })}
```

now my state is like this:

```
this.state ={
    selectedQuestion:[],
    editValue0:'',
    editValue1:'',
    editValue2:'',
    editValue3:''
}
```

and the onchange event `onChange={this.checkRadioChange}` is like this:

```
checkRadioChange=(event)=>{

 this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value},()=>{
   // console.log('this.state.selectedQuestion[0].options: ',this.state.selectedQuestion[0].options)

    console.log("THIS.STATE",this.state)
})
```

the problem is that i am not able to equate the  dynamic value in input to the respective state properties, something like :

`return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)`

should change to

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue0" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>) 
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue1" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue2" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value="this.state.editvalue3" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

as the `li` is iterating. So I tried something like:

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value={this.state.editvalue + {a}} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

and

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value={this.state.editvalue + a}" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

and

```
return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value={'this.state.editvalue' + a}" onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

but iit either throws error or shows `undefined[object][object]` result.

Note: the `selectedQuestion` is coming dynamically, so pls dont confuse on `selectedQuestion:[]` in `this.state`

but iit either throws error or shows `undefined[object][object]` result.

Note: 1) The `selectedQuestion` is coming dynamically, so pls dont confuse on `selectedQuestion:[]` in `this.state`.

```
  2) For testing, i tried  return(<li key={e.id}><input type="text" name={"editValue"+a} value={this.state.editvalue0} onChange={this.checkRadioChange} /> </li>)
```

and it was successfully updating the `editvalue0` in `this.state`, so if i am just able set the dyunamic state in value attribute, it will do the trick.

```
  3) To test, I tried giving a static value to `value` attribute like so:
value={this.state.editValue1}
```

and I added a static value to the `this.state.editValue1` like so:

this.state ={
    selectedQuestion:[],
    editValue0:'',
    editValue1:'one',
    editValue2:'',
    editValue3:''
}

and it applied the value of `one` to all the iterated inputs, and I was also able to get the updated value inside the `editValue1` in `this.state`.

But when i did this: `value={t.opt}`

then i was able to get each value previously added in json, but as i typed, the words were not adding in the textbox (as expected). Ny json is like this:

```
[
    {"id":1,
     "question":"Which continent india belongs to?",
     "options":[
        {"opt":"Australia"},
    {"opt":"Europe"},
    {"opt":"Asia"},
    {"opt":"Africa"}

      ]

    },

    {"id":2,
     "question":"New Delhi is capital of which country?",
     "options":[
        {"opt":"Croatia"},
    {"opt":"India"},
    {"opt":"America"},
    {"opt":"Iraq"}
      ]

    },

    {"id":3,
     "question":"Who was the first man to step on Moon?",
     "options":[
        {"opt":"Abdul Kalam"},
    {"opt":"Albert Einstein"},
    {"opt":"Sheldon Cooper"},
    {"opt":"Salman Khan"}
      ]

    }
    ]




  4) You are welcome to point out any better way, but please do answer on the dynamic value also. Thanks
```

Comment: Could you create a small codepen to demonstrate it ? You wrote a detailed question but it would help to see it as real code. This would also make it easier to show you how to do it excatly. I think you want to add the index to the map function like this: map(e,i)=> {} with I being the index. You can append that to the value to create dynamic values instead of the static a

Comment: ok i will try to make codepen, but a is not static, it is the iterated index of options:  {e.options.map((t,a)=>{

Answer (score 0):

I've created a codepen example to demonstrate your problem case, I'm not sure what's the root cause of you problem, but I was able to sync the value between react's state and the UI input accordingly.

```
class ListElement extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      selectedQuestions: [1,2,3,4],
      editValue0: 'value0',
      editValue1: 'value1',
      editValue2: 'value2',
      editValue3: 'value3'
    }
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.selectedQuestions.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <label>{`editValue${index}`}</label>
              <input type="text"
                value={this.state[`editValue${index}`]}
                name={`editValue${index}`}
                onChange={this.onChange}/>
            </li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the link to the codepen.io: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXgWoM

Hope it helps :)